# How to find any app in our computer without typing the file location using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently building an AI like google assistant. I want to open any app using python. How do  I do that without typing the file location. Like we press the windows key and search our app, I mean like that.
I tried this:

```
import os
os.system("start ms-settings-DesiredApp:")
```

But this doesn't work for all apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think is so easy. I mean I tried (*on windows 10*) to search different types of apps and I just finde some of the. That is because not all of them was installed.

- Are some one file.exe what will work with out to install it (this type will not show on search bar)
- Are some of them what are just an archive, and if is extracted will work fine (godot for the example: i get back just the archive name under folders tab)
- And some of them have the option to not add folder on task bar and maybe for that reason some of the have no result in search bar

I do not know if is possible or impossible but maybe will not work like a quick search and you need to make another option to let the player/user to specifie where to search in case the file has not a start shortcut

Comment: But most of the apps are shown on the windows search bar, right? Even so how can I use it?

Comment: I think [this will help](https://pypi.org/project/winapps/) you better then OS library

Comment: Thanks, winapps is better.